# How to schedule tasks with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the latest version of ASP.NET Core to develop a game using SignalR. I want to schedule only one thing...the end of the game signal after the game starts.

First I tried Coravel, but I couldn't figure out how to dynamically schedule tasks. Then I tried Hangfire. First it was failing because it was creating a new Hub, then I tried passing my Hub to my task and got all kinds of serialization errors. Chroniton appears to be too old to be relied on for production.

So how am I to schedule a task from inside a Hub that will run on that Hub? I can't imagine this is an uncommon scenario.

Added code that showcases the issue:

```
public async Task MatchStartRequest()
{
    var GroupName = PlayersAndGroups[Context.ConnectionId];
    await Clients.Group(GroupName).SendAsync("StartGame");
    GroupsAndRooms[GroupName].GameStarted = true;
    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => EndGame(GroupName), System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}

public async Task EndGame(string GroupName)
{
    await Clients.Group(GroupName).SendAsync("EndGame");
    PlayersAndGroups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
    GroupsAndRooms[GroupName].ConnectionIdsAndPlayers.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
    if (GroupsAndRooms[GroupName].ConnectionIdsAndPlayers.Count == 0)
    {
        GroupsAndRooms.Remove(GroupName);
    }
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, GroupName);
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the first line of EndGame (the await SendAsync function), I can see that the server is trying to send the message to a null Hub, which of course does not work. If I edit the EndGame method to pass the Hub to it as well as the GroupName, the server gives me a bunch of serialization errors. Is there perhaps a Hub ID that I can pass to get to that hub from the server?

Comment: You need to post the code that you tried that's not working. This is certainly doable with something like Hangfire (I haven't personally used the others you mentioned), but without the code you tried, it's impossible to say why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: I added example code showcasing the issue, any ideas? Thanks! Also, I tried to do this in a simpler way and just delay the thread for 60 seconds after the game starts, and that sort of works, but my client library is expecting the server to finish the MatchStart command before it will send any further commands, so that solution is also infeasible for me because the last player to join (the one that sends the MatchStart method) will not send any further events to the server.

Comment: I seem to have gotten this working by injecting the Hub context into the Hub itself and then calling the method on that. I will add the code as soon as I test it a little more.